# добавление данных в выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица *table*. Есть *input* для ввода пользователем данных. И поле с выпадающим списком (*select*).
Нужно введенные в *input* данные добавлять в поле с выпадающим списком. Без использования *submit*, без отправки на сервер.

Comment: а таблица то тут при чем?

Comment: просто работаю с таблицей, в ней находятся данные и  поле для ввода input. добавляю к ней новую строку с введенными из input данными, введены они в новую ячейку таблицы(без отправки их на сервер).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то вроде такого?

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
   var txt = $("input").val();
   var check =  "#sel option[value='" +txt + "']"; // $.escapeSelector(txt)
   if($(check).length != 0) return;
   
   $("<option>").val(txt)
                .text(txt)
                .appendTo("#sel");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<button id="add">Добавить</button>
<select id="sel"></select>
```